On the definition on almost sure convergence
I am a bit confused about the definition of almost sure convergence. Of course, we say that $X_n \underset{n \to \infty}{\longrightarrow} X$ almost surely if
$$
\mathbb{P} \big( \{ \lim_{n \to \infty} X_n = X \} \big) = 1
$$
The almost sure event of convergence is
$$
\big\{ \lim_{n \to \infty} X_n = X \big\} = \big\{ \lim_{n \to \infty} | X_n - X | = 0 \big\} = \big\{ \forall \, \varepsilon > 0 \quad \exists \, n \geq 1 : \forall \, m \geq n \quad |X_m - X| \leq \varepsilon \big\}
$$
and of course the "$\forall \, \varepsilon > 0$" is an uncountable intersection.
But the wikipedia page on the topic says that almost sure convergence can be equivalently expressed as
$$
\mathbb{P} \big( \big\{ \limsup_{n \to \infty} |X_n - X| > \varepsilon \big\} \big) = 0 \quad \forall \, \varepsilon > 0
$$
which is of course the same as
$$
\mathbb{P} \big( \big\{ \limsup_{n \to \infty} |X_n - X| \leq \varepsilon \big\} \big) = 1 \quad \forall \, \varepsilon > 0
$$
that is,
$$
\forall \, \varepsilon > 0 \quad \mathbb{P} \big( \big\{ \exists \, n \geq 1 : \forall \, m \geq n \quad |X_m - X| \leq \varepsilon \big\} \big) = 1
$$
But (because of the intersection being uncountable) this seems different than the statement that I got from the definition of limit, which is
$$
\mathbb{P} \big( \big\{ \forall \, \varepsilon > 0 \quad \exists \, n \geq 1 : \forall \, m \geq n \quad |X_m - X| \leq \varepsilon \big\} \big) = 1
$$
and I feel stuck on this point.
Moreover, I suspect that in the first statement (with "$\forall \, \varepsilon > 0$" outside) $n$ should be intended as random, while in the other statement $n$ should be taken as deterministic. However, I wouldn't see any sign that this should be the case beyond mere speculation. I would say that $n$ should be intended as random the whole time.
Any help would be much appreciated.

would $|X_m-X| \leqslant \frac{1}{k}$ eventually for each $k\in\mathbb N$  convince you?

I considered converting the uncountable intersection over $\varepsilon > 0$ into a countable intersection over $\frac{1}{k} , \quad k \geq 1$ and this would indeed make the two statements equivalent. That is, it would be $$\mathbb{P} \big( \big{ \forall , \varepsilon > 0 \quad \exists , n \geq 1 : \forall , m \geq n \quad |X_m - X| \leq \varepsilon \big} \big) = 1 \iff \forall , \varepsilon > 0 \quad \mathbb{P} \big( \big{ \exists , n \geq 1 : \forall , m \geq n \quad |X_m - X| \leq \varepsilon \big} \big) = 1$$ \ But a prof once told me that this conversion changes the statement.

You must have misunderstood something. (Un)countability is not an issue here. If we have a family of events indexed by positive numbers, we can sort the trajectories into a sequence of events.

Note that, for $Z_n = |X- X_n|,$ the statement $\forall \varepsilon, P(\limsup Z_n > \varepsilon) = 0 $ is equivalent to $\forall \varepsilon > 0, P(\limsup Z_n \le \varepsilon) = 1$, but is not equivalent to $\forall \varepsilon > 0, P(\liminf Z_n \le \varepsilon) = 1$, which is a weaker statement. As a counterexample, consider $Z_n$ that are independent, with $P(Z_n = 0) = 1 -P(Z_n = 1) = 1/n$ (I'll leave it to you to work out the difference).

Given this, the equivalence demanded is that $P(Z_n \to 0) = 1 \iff \forall \varepsilon > 0, P(\limsup Z_n > \varepsilon) = 0$. But notice by using the nonnegativity of $Z_n$ that $\{Z_n \to 0\}^c = \{\exists \varepsilon > 0 : \limsup Z_n > \varepsilon \}$. So the question is the same as showing
$$ P(\exists \varepsilon > 0: \limsup Z_n > \varepsilon) = 0 \iff \forall \varepsilon > 0, P(\limsup Z_n > \varepsilon) = 0. $$ This is not obvious because the second term "pulls out" the $\varepsilon$ from within the probability.
Of course, the forward implication in is easy: for any $\varepsilon > 0,$ $\{\limsup Z_n > \varepsilon\} \subset \{\exists \varepsilon > 0: \limsup Z_n > \varepsilon\},$ and the latter event having probability $0$ implies the former to have the same. So the question is why the reverse implication holds.
For this, the main observation is that  $$ \{\exists \varepsilon > 0 : \limsup Z_n > \varepsilon\} = \{ \exists \varepsilon > 0, \varepsilon \in \mathbb{Q}: \limsup Z_n > \varepsilon\}, $$ which holds because for any $x > 0,$ there is always a rational in the interval $(0,x]$. Let me denote $\mathbb{Q}_+ = \mathbb{Q} \cap (0,\infty)$.
Now, observe that due to the countability of the union over $\mathbb{Q}_+$, $$P(\exists \varepsilon \in \mathbb{Q}_+ :\limsup Z_n > \varepsilon) \le \sum_{\varepsilon \in \mathbb{Q}_+} P(\limsup Z_n > \varepsilon). $$ But notice that under the hypothesis, the sum is $0$ for each $\varepsilon > 0$ and hence for each $\varepsilon \in \mathbb{Q}_+$, and thus the hypothesis implies that $P(\exists \varepsilon > 0: \limsup Z_n > \varepsilon) = 0$.

Many thanks. I understand that you claimed that intersection over rationals is the same as over the positive reals because of $\mathbb{Q}$ being dense in $\mathbb{R}$. Then you used the countability of the union to apply countable additivity of probabilities. So, indeed we have $\mathbb{P} \big( \big{ \forall , \varepsilon > 0 \quad \exists , n \geq 1 : \forall , m \geq n \quad |X_m - X| \leq \varepsilon \big} \big) = 1 \iff \forall , \varepsilon > 0 \quad \mathbb{P} \big( \big{ \exists , n \geq 1 : \forall , m \geq n \quad |X_m - X| \leq \varepsilon \big} \big) = 1$. Am I correct?

Yup. In particular, the notation in the answer sets ${\forall \epsilon, \exists n \ge 1 \cdots \le \varepsilon } = {\forall \varepsilon, \limsup Z_n \le \varepsilon} = {\exists \varepsilon : \limsup Z_n > \varepsilon}^c,$ and similarly with the $\varepsilon$ pulled out of the event. The answer works with the complementary events, and so uses the fact that the union over all $\varepsilon$ is equal to the union over only rational $\varepsilon$ (but of course you can take complements).

Define events ( in some $(\Omega,\mathcal F,P)$ )
$$ B_n(\varepsilon) := \{|X_n-X|>\varepsilon\} \quad (\varepsilon >0, n\in\mathbb N) $$
as well as
$$ B(\varepsilon) := \limsup B_n(\varepsilon) = \{|X_n-X|>\varepsilon\ \mbox{i.o}\}.  $$
Let $B := \{X_n\to X\}$. Note that
$$ B^c = \bigcup _{\varepsilon>0} B(\varepsilon) \overset{*}= \bigcup _{k=1}^\infty B\left(\frac{1}{k}\right)\in\mathcal F.\tag{1}\label{eq:1} $$
Suppose $X_n\to X$ a.s. Then, $P(B)=1$ together with \eqref{eq:1} implies that $P(B(\varepsilon))=0$ for all $\varepsilon >0$.
Conversely, if $P(B(\varepsilon)) =0$ for every $\varepsilon >0$, then, again by \eqref{eq:1}, $P(B) = 1$.

The equality * follows from $\delta \leqslant \varepsilon \Rightarrow B(\varepsilon)\subseteq B(\delta)$

Thanks. I guess that the fact that uncountability is not an issue here and that we can indeed interchange intersections over $\varepsilon > 0$ with intersections over $\frac{1}{k} , ; k≥1$ follows from the family of sets $\big( { |Xn−X|>ε } \big)_{\varepsilon > 0}$ being monotone. Did I get it straight?
